# Как переводить на другие языки варианты ответов в django-filter?

Tags: django-filter

```
DATE_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Сегодня'),
        (1, 'Завтра'),
        (2, 'На этой неделе'),
        (3, 'Пятница + выходные'),
        (4, 'В этом месяце'),
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

DATE_CHOICES = (
    (0, _('Сегодня'),),
    (1, _('Завтра'),),
    (2, _('На этой неделе'),),
    (3, _('В этом месяце'),),
    (4, _('В следующем месяце'),),
)
```